# Get Absolute Url keeps directing to one particular id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

Good day, I have a Django project where I want to display an order list and detail. All seems to work perfectly but the link only links to one particular id ( for instance id 66). I have tried deleting the particular order id from the admin panel, thinking maybe the URL would just reset, but I get the URL id incremented, now it's no longer id 66 but 67. Pls how can I fix this? here are my codes:

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    braintree_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon, related_name='orders', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[
        MinValueValidator(0),
        MaxValueValidator(100)
    ])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('orders:orderdetail', args=[self.id])
```

**views.py**

```
def order_list(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    current_user = request.user
    success = Order.objects.filter(user=current_user.id).filter(paid=True)
    fail = Order.objects.filter(user=current_user.id).filter(paid=False)
    return render(request, 'orders/order/order_list.html', {
        'success': success,
        'fail': fail,
        'current_user': current_user,
        'orders':orders,
    })


def order_detail(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
    return render(request, 'orders/order/order_detail.html', {'order': order})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'orders'

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', views.order_create, name='order_create'),
    path('admin/order/<int:order_id>/', views.admin_order_detail, name='admin_order_detail'),
    path('admin/order/<int:order_id>/pdf/', views.admin_order_pdf, name='admin_order_pdf'),
    path('addtocart/<int:id>', views.addtocart, name='addtocart'),
    path('myorder/', views.order_list, name='orderlist'),
    path('myorder/detail/<int:order_id>/', views.order_detail, name='orderdetail'),

]
```

**html**

```
{% for order in orders %}
<a href="{{ order.get_absolute_url }}" style="position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px;">
View Details
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**full html**

```
<div class="col-md-9">
{% for od in success %}
<div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
<div class="row no-gutters">
<div class="col-md-3">
<img alt="product img" class="card-img" src="...">
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
<div class="card-body" style="position: relative;">
<h5 class="card-title">Product {{ od.id }}</h5>
{% for order in orders %}
<a href="{{ order.get_absolute_url }}" style="position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px;">
View Details
</a>
{% endfor %}
<p class="card-text">
<mark style="color: whitesmoke; background-color: brown;border-radius: 3px;font-weight: bold;">{{transaction}}</mark>
</p>
<p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Delivered at
                                                    {{od.reference_id}}</small></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

The URL I get is like this `/orders/myorder/detail/66/`
I'm gonna add pictures to make it less abstract
[image: the cursor hovers over the view detail but the URL directs to 66][image: same]
Thanks.

Comment: i don't understand your need.  
what are you expecting ?

Comment: I have more than 1 order that is listed and wants to display each of them, but the absolute URL link to one order

Comment: get_absolute_url() is intended to point to a single object. Please have a look at the django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

Comment: can you share your full html file ? it's called from /myorder/ ? i think you change the orders context.

Comment: @EricMartin I've edited it.

Comment: @Marco exactly, but it's not working as it should

Comment: @EricMartin It's probably gonna be in the orders context as you've said. I'm looking into it

Comment: Why do you pass multiple order results (orders, fail, success) to the template and not only one?
Secondly, which confuses me: Why do you iterate first through success orders and then again on full order result inside that? I think the id is used from the outer ```od in success```.

Comment: yeah, I just realized that I've fixed it. Thanks

Comment: you can kindly mark my answer :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just like @EricMartin said, it was the context of the order
I realized I had  `{% for od in success %}` and `{% for order in orders %}`
I guess they're not on good terms with each other and since orders is in success, I removed the `{% for order in orders %}` loop and all seems peaceful again :)